# jquery UI changing class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am working on a project and need some help. Have these div's that are droppable via the jQuery UI. Everything works great and I can drag and drop, but I want to change the class or something so the div I am dragging has a certain opacity. Here is my jquery:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( ".recipe-item" ).draggable({helper : 'clone',revert: "valid"});
    $( ".cal-date" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Recipe Added!" );
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is some of the html:

```
<div class="recipe-item">
    Chicken noodle soup
</div>
<div class="cal-date">
<p>Drop Recipe Here</p>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.recipe-item {
    background-color: #043A6b;
    width: 200px;
    height: 70px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border:2px solid #B0B0B0;
    color:#fff;
    z-index: 10;
    margin-top: 10px;
    opacity: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
.recipe-item-dragged {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.cal-date {
    background: #B0B0B0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    color:#fff;
}
```

So I can either toggle the dragged class or set the css with jQuery. I know in jQuery you can do `$(item).css("opacity", "0.5");` or along those lines but I am not sure how I would do it in this case since the 'this' in the droppable event is the other div and I would have multiple `.recipe-items`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually turned out to be quite simple:

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ opacity: 0.35 });
```

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
.toggleClass(".recipe-item-dragged", true);
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
drop: function( event, ui ) {
  ...
  ui.draggable.addClass('recipe-item-dragged');
  //OR
  ui.helper.addClass('recipe-item-dragged');
  ....
}
```

If you want to change the class when dragging starts:

```
$( ".recipe-item" ).draggable({
   helper : 'clone',
   revert: "valid",
   drag: function( event, ui ) {
       ui.helper.addClass('recipe-item-dragged');
       //OR
       $(this).addClass('recipe-item-dragged');
   }   

});
```

Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia